# How do I fit my data to one sheet when exporting to pdf in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to export a specific range on one of my excel sheets to pdf. It cuts off a small part at the bottom and puts it on the next page. My question is : How do I change my code below to allow for a "fit to one page" option and how do I make the orientation landscape?

```
Sub printdispatchsheet()
Sheets("DispatchSheet").Range("A1:J48").ExportAsFixedFormat 
Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:= _
"c:\Users\name\Desktop\DispatchSheet.pdf", Quality:= _
xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Check [Fit to one page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fit-to-one-page-f3015be3-e007-4762-90a7-19ebc8052511?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Actually, you can even record a macro to do this and adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try and see if this works? Also see if setting your print areas properly helps, if not modify that part of the code to `True`

```
Sub printdispatchsheet()

With Sheets("DispatchSheet")
    .PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PageSetup.Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With

Sheets("DispatchSheet").Range("A1:J48").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="c:\Users\name\Desktop\DispatchSheet.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True

 End Sub
```